# The best way to upload images to cloudinary? MERN stack

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cloudinary

I'm a beginner in the MERN stack, but I'm trying to create a social network application with the help of various tutorials on YouTube when I get stuck. I need a little more experienced thinking on how best to upload an image to the cloudinary. When I study, I want to learn in the right direction how people work in companies and how they work in the real world.

I found two types of code on youtube that works the same (uploads an image to cloudinary). I wonder which is better. A new API is created in one tutorial, something like this:

```
cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: '',
  api_key: '',
  api_secret: '',
});

router.post('/upload', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
  try {
    if (!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0)
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No files were uploaded.' });

    const file = req.files.file;
    if (file.size > 1024 * 1024) {
      removeTmp(file.tempFilePath);
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'Size too large' });
    }

    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png') {
      removeTmp(file.tempFilePath);
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'File format is incorrect.' });
    }
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
      file.tempFilePath,
      { folder: 'test' },
      async (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        removeTmp(file.tempFilePath);

        res.json({ public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
  }
});

router.post('/destroy', authenticateUser, (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { public_id } = req.body;
    if (!public_id) return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'No images Selected' });

    cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(public_id, async (err, result) => {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.json({ msg: 'Deleted Image' });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).json({ msg: err.message });
  }
});

const removeTmp = path => {
  fs.unlink(path, err => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
};

export default router;
```

And the other shot does it all the same from the controller. For example if I want to make a new post my controller looks like this:

```
export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
  const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.image, {
    folder: 'posts',
  });

  const { description, image } = req.body;

  if (!image) {
    throw new BadRequestError('Image is required');
  }

  const user = await User.findById(req.user.userId);

  const newPost = new Post({
    description,
    image: {
      public_id: myCloud.public_id,
      url: myCloud.secure_url,
    },
    username: user.username,
    avatar: user.avatar,
    user: req.user.userId,
  });

  const post = await newPost.save();

  res.status(StatusCodes.CREATED).json({ post });
};
```

I create an image in the controller and upload it when I submit the form in react. They both work the same, I tried, but I'm interested in whether it's necessary to make a new endpoint or it's enough to upload an image from the controller, delete an image from the controller, etc.

Comment: You could consider using the Node SDK for your case as it wraps Cloudinary's REST API with additional helper methods (see this [link](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_integration))

Answer (score 0):

You can use multer module for uploading content in the directory and if you want to upload in S3 bucket then you have to use module accordingly.

For multer -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer

For multer-S3 -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer-s3

Comment: I use https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-fileupload